# Two functions in Mininero to derive Monero address from hexadecimal seed?

Tags: address, mininero

In Mininero's code, there are [two functions](https://github.com/monero-project/mininero/blob/master/mininero.py#L325) that seem to derive monero addresses, `getAddr` and `getAddrMM`, but only the former agrees with the address provided by monero-wallet-cli.

What is `getAddrMM`, and why is it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MM` is probably an abbreviation for MyMonero. Note that, in comparison with the standard private view key, the private view key of MyMonero accounts are derived differently. [That is:](https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html)

> **MyMonero Style** – This is similar to 2., but uses a 13 word seed instead of a 25 word seed. The 13 words convert to a 128-bit integer that is used for both spend and view key derivation, in the following form: the 128-bit integer is hashed with Keccak-256 to produce a 256-bit integer, *a*. *a* is sent to *sc_reduce32*, which returns the *Private Spend Key*. *a* is hashed once more with Keccak-256 to produce a second 256-bit integer, *b*. *b* is then sent to *sc_reduce32*, which returns the *Private View Key*. You may have noticed a critical difference between this style and the Electrum Style: MyMonero's *Private View Key* derivation is done by hashing random integer *a*, while Electrum Style derivation is done by hashing the *Private Spend Key*. This means that 13 and 25 word seeds are not compatible – it is not possible to create an Electrum Style seed (and account) that matches a MyMonero Style seed (and account) or vice versa; the view keypair will always be different. You can test out this style above with the "Random MyMonero" button. To backup MyMonero accounts, save the 13 word seed; you can currently "restore" using MyMonero only (you're really just logging in) – Simplewallet does not currently support 13-word seeds.

Hence, MiniNero uses two different functions to derive Monero addresses. Lastly, note that `simplewallet` was renamed to `monero-wallet-cli`.

**Additional reading:**

[Why are Monero addresses so long?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/277/why-are-monero-addresses-so-long)